# Animating the removal of a UIView with constraints

Tags: ios, swift

I have a vertical list of `UIView`s that are not in a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView` or anything like that, they are simply views added to a `UIScrollView` positioned in rows using constraints (these views don't link to anything so I did not put them into a table view). If I wanted to remove one or more of these views upon a user action and I wanted that view to animate out while the views beneath it slid up to fill the void, is this the perfect time to use a `UITableView`?

I was under the impression that the `UITableView` is really to be used for master/detail situations like lists that link to detail view controllers. Or is there a clean way of animating the adding and removal of these views using their constraints?

Comment: You can use a table view any way you want. Your cells don’t need to enable further navigation. If it fitted your app and design, you could have a cell navigate backwards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vertical Stack View. It suitable for your requirement.
It adjust space automatically when one view is removed from list of views